# How do I contact Google to request special permissions on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, cryptocurrency

I was wondering how do I contact Google to negotiate a deal. I wanted to burst coin mine on GCP. As said in the ToS it says that Free Trail doesn't allow to do that. So I upgraded but found that paid accounts can only mine if they have written permission from Google. Which is why I am here now. I was wondering if there was an email or someone at Google I can talk to about allowing me to burst the coin. Burst coin is a cryptocurrency that uses storage to mine instead of all those fancy machines. I only plan to use storage and not do dual miner(some miners do that). If needed I can run another and connect hard disks over the internet. I just didn't want to start doing something without asking for permission.

Edit: I have bad grammar. I basically said I need permission to use their cloud storage and/or their compute engine to mine burst coins. If I can't use their compute engine but their cloud storage I am willing to host hardware myself I just need storage to be a host since I don't have Terabytes of storage on hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact GCP through their contact page over [here](https://cloud.google.com/contact). I would say that you should contact the compliance team, nevertheless, there is no guarantee that they will be willing to let you use the infrastructure for cryptocurrency mining.

Additionally, do not try to do this before their response as it is a violation of the [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/terms), and may lead to a suspension on the service:

> 4.2 Other Suspension. Notwithstanding Section 4.1 (AUP Violations) Google may immediately Suspend all or part of Customer's use of the Services if: (a) Google believes Customer's or any Customer End User's use of the Services could adversely impact the Services, other customers' or their end users' use of the Services, or the Google network or servers used to provide the Services, which may include use of the Services for cryptocurrency mining without Google's prior written approval;

Hope you find this useful.